# Events not showing up with full calendar using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I am having trouble getting my events to show up on my full calendar app. The calendar shows up and when I manually enter events they show up as well. But when I attempt to pull from the JSON file it does not work. This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: '/events/json',
        error: function() 
        {
            alert("error");
         },
            success: function()
         {
            console.log("successfully loaded");
         }
       }

        });
    });
</script>
```

And I am getting the error that:

```
jquery.self bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10255 GET https://APP/events/json?start=2018-02-25&end=2018-04-08&_=1520803262179 404 (Not Found)
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

EDIT:

the following is shown when I navigate to https://APP/events.json:

```
[{"id":5,"title":"Example","description":"example","start_time":"2018-03-13T01:00:00.000Z","end_time":"2018-03-13T01:10:00.000Z","created_at":"2018-03-13T01:10:48.005Z","updated_at":"2018-03-13T01:10:48.005Z"}]
```

Comment: do you have a events json action imeplemented ? Or do you mean `/events.json` ? Route Defined ?

Comment: check you URL is correct. This is not afullcalendar issue, the browser just can't find anything at the URL where you told it to go and look for events. If you don't know what a 404 error is, google it

Comment: @rdcrist does my answer help you solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

change `url: '/events/json',` to `url: '/events.json',`

add in routes.rb

```
resources :events
```

Add action in controller events_controller.rb

```
def index
  @events = Event.all # or whatever you query will look like, maybe filter after month
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'index' }
    format.json { render json: @events }
  end
end
```

Comment: I did this and I am still getting the same error :/

Comment: Can you show your log output again if you use events/json and if you use events.json

Comment: It started working! But now im receiving a "fullcalendar.self-.jsUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined" error . I think there is too much info in my JSON file (the created at and edited at bits) but I have no idea how to change that

Comment: It tries to call hasTime on a object or an attribute. Maybe calendar js expect attributes you are not providing.